# What packages are loaded?

Tags: package-management

I would like to load 22.10 "fresh" rather than upgrade 22.04.1 in place.  Before I do that I would like to see what packages I've loaded as a guide of what to re-load after the new install.  Is there a command to list packages I've installed?

Comment: `dpkg --get-selections | awk '$2 == "install" {print $1}' > packages.list.save`  The package.list.save file contains the packages. Atl  least I do it this way in Debian.

Comment: You can *upgrade via re-install* using the installation media; and have your *manually installed* packages auto-reinstall (if available in the new release; ie. 22.10, in Ubuntu repositories) if you're using a desktop system. Just re-use the existing partition(s) & do **not** format, the lack of format causes the *manually installed* packages to be noted; before system directories are erased; then new install is made, then **if internet** is available the *manually installed* packages noted earlier get re-installed & user asked to reboot. No user file is touched (assuming no format of course)

Comment: It is better to create a text file with the commands you issue during the lifetime of your install. You can also save settings if you do not set them through gui but find the command line method. It saves me an hour each re-install ;-)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you all.  @guiverc - There some I don't want re-installed on the new release.  I will make note of that for the next time.  Can I assume it will also leave my HOME dir untouched?

Comment: If you don't format, the $HOME directory (ie. *user files*) is untouched (*be it the same, or separate partition*).  I describe it [here](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/testing-checklist-understanding-the-testcases/2743) where Lubuntu call it "*Install using existing partition*" (I prefer "*upgrade via re-install*" but it's expected to be "*Repair Installation*" returning to a menu option for the 23.04 installation media instead of triggered as I describe (*it was an option long ago*). The page I linked was written for QA-testers not end-users, but it's described many times on this site too.